# ToggleClass animate with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a section on my website that when a user clicks I would like it to expand, I'm using the jQuery's  toggleClass for this

```
   jQuery('.menux').click(function() {
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('is-active');
        jQuery('.a').toggleClass('a1');
        jQuery('.b').toggleClass('b1');
        jQuery('.c').toggleClass('c1');
    });
```

When clicked, the animation runs perfectly. But when I clicked the second time, the animation does not appear. different when clicked the first time, the animation runs slowly down. When i using `jQuery('.c').toggleClass('c1', 2000);` <-- duration,
Not work!. How do I use animation in clicks a second time? In order to ascend slowly upwards

This my test https://jsfiddle.net/u6aztsgt/1/

Comment: what are you expecting when you clicked the second time !!

Comment: You are not using jQuery at all in this JSFiddle - you're using pure vanilla JavaScript to add and remove a class. Then your CSS has a keyframe animation designed to show when the class is added. You'd need to play this animation in reverse (which is natively supported by the CSS `animation:` property) when the class is removed.

Comment: sorry look update https://jsfiddle.net/u6aztsgt/1/

Comment: On click you are adding class a1,b1,c2 these class have css3 animation so on adding it shows with animation. On second click you are removing that class all of sudden so u dont get animation tr. Try using jquery fadeIn, fadeout with required delay.

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a new animation and toggle that on second click or vice versa.
You can use this css for the second click animation,

```
@-webkit-keyframes dropUp{from{margin-top: 0px;opacity: 1}to{margin-top: -20px;opacity: 0}}
@-moz-keyframes dropUp{from{margin-top: 0px;opacity: 1}to{margin-top: -20px;opacity: 0}}
@keyframes dropUp{from{margin-top: 0px;opacity: 1}to{margin-top: -20px;opacity: 0}}
.a2, .b2, .c2 {
  -webkit-animation: dropUp 1s;
  -moz-animation: dropUp 1s;
  animation: dropUp 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
}

.a2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.b2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0.5s;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

.c2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
```